# Filter out blue patches in greenest pixel composite - GEE Quality Mosaic NDVI change image Sentinel-2

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, filter, composite

I am making greenest pixel composites from Sentinel-2 SR (using the quality mosaic tool in GEE based on NDVI). I then subtract two greenest pixel composites to get a change in NDVI image.

These blue patches are causing problems. Does someone know how to filter them out efficiently?
I could try the aggressive cloud filter algorithm, but it's a lot slower.

[image]

```
        // PRE-EVENT IMAGE
        // Dates over which to create a composite.
        var pre_start = ee.Date('2023-06-01');
        var pre_end = ee.Date('2023-08-07');
        
        // POST-EVENT IMAGE
        // Dates over which to create a composite.
        var post_start = ee.Date('2023-08-08');
        var post_end = ee.Date('2023-09-27');

Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point([10.75125, 61.81312]), 14)

// #########################  NDVI Function ##############################
// Add NDVI  
  function addS2NDVI(image) {
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
  }

// ###############   Import Sentinel-2 Image Collection  ##################

// Sentinel-2 surface reflectance data for the composite.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR');

// #########################   Make S2 Pre Image  #########################

var pre_filtered = S2.filterDate(pre_start, pre_end)
    .map(addS2NDVI);

var pre_image = ee.Image(pre_filtered.qualityMosaic('NDVI')).select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'NDVI']);

// #########################   Make S2 Post Image  #########################

var post_filtered = S2.filterDate(post_start, post_end)  
    .map(addS2NDVI);

var post_image = ee.Image(post_filtered.qualityMosaic('NDVI')).select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'NDVI'])

// ########################   Make S2 Difference Image  #######################

var diff = post_image.subtract(pre_image);

// #########################   Visualize and display  #########################

// dNDVI
var dNDVI_params = {bands:"NDVI", min:-0.6, max:0.1};

// RGB true colour
var viz_rgb = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.5};

Map.addLayer(pre_image, viz_rgb, 'pre-event RGB composite');
Map.addLayer(post_image, viz_rgb, 'post-event RGB composite', false);
Map.addLayer(diff, dNDVI_params, 'dNDVI', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to work based on this post:
[Mask Sentinel-2 image using SCL product in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423823/mask-sentinel-2-image-using-scl-product-in-google-earth-engine)

[image: Greenest-pixel composite filtering using SCL bands]

I filtered by the SCL band using the following function. This is still fast.

```
// Filter by SCL bands
  var s2_clear_sky = function(image){  
  // 1.Locate SCL product
  var scl = image.select('SCL');

  // 2.Apply mask to the image
  // Select values: 1) greater than 3 and less than 8, or 2) equal to 2 or 7
  var wantedPixels = scl.gt(3).and(scl.lt(6))
                              .or(scl.eq(2))
                              .or(scl.eq(7));
  return image.updateMask(wantedPixels);
};
```

[image]

The script is then as follows:

```
        // PRE-EVENT IMAGE
        // Dates over which to create a composite.
        var pre_start = ee.Date('2023-06-01');
        var pre_end = ee.Date('2023-08-07');
        
        // POST-EVENT IMAGE
        // Dates over which to create a composite.
        var post_start = ee.Date('2023-08-08');
        var post_end = ee.Date('2023-09-27');

Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point([10.75125, 61.81312]), 14)

// #########################  S2 Functions ##############################
// Add NDVI  
  function addS2NDVI(image) {
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
  }
  
// Filter by SCL bands
  var s2_clear_sky = function(image){  
  // 1.Locate SCL product
  var scl = image.select('SCL');
 
  // 2.Apply mask to the image
  // Select values: 1) greater than 3 and less than 8, or 2) equal to 2 or 7
  var wantedPixels = scl.gt(3).and(scl.lt(6))
                              .or(scl.eq(2))
                              .or(scl.eq(7));
  return image.updateMask(wantedPixels);
};


// ###############   Import Sentinel-2 Image Collection  ##################

// Sentinel-2 surface reflectance data for the composite.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR');


// #########################   Make S2 Pre Image  #########################

var pre_filtered = S2.filterDate(pre_start, pre_end)
    .map(s2_clear_sky)
    .map(addS2NDVI);

var pre_image = ee.Image(pre_filtered.qualityMosaic('NDVI')).select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'NDVI']);

// #########################   Make S2 Post Image  #########################

var post_filtered = S2.filterDate(post_start, post_end)  
    .map(s2_clear_sky)
    .map(addS2NDVI);

var post_image = ee.Image(post_filtered.qualityMosaic('NDVI')).select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'NDVI'])

// ########################   Make S2 Difference Image  #######################

var diff = post_image.subtract(pre_image);

// #########################   Visualize and display  #########################

// dNDVI
var dNDVI_params = {bands:"NDVI", min:-0.6, max:0.1};

// RGB true colour
var viz_rgb = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.5};

Map.addLayer(pre_image, viz_rgb, 'pre-event RGB composite');
Map.addLayer(post_image, viz_rgb, 'post-event RGB composite', false);
Map.addLayer(diff, dNDVI_params, 'dNDVI', false);
```